# htaccess redirect for images

Tags: html, image, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to have all relational links to images (eg "/images/filename.ext") be redirected to something like "http://otherdomain.com/images/filename.ext" so that the relational image addresses are actually looking for the images on the other domain

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/images/$1 [NC, P]
```

and:

```
RedirectPermanent /images http://otherdomain.com/images
```

But to no avail. It's been a long time since I've written [htaccess](/questions/tagged/htaccess) stuff and wasnt that great to begin with ;) so at a bit of a loss.

I'm re-writing some code for a friend and it would be good if he could just copy and paste the finished HTML without worrying about the image links needing changing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My knwoledge in this area is also very limited, but I looked at some working examples here, and they may help you:

```
1 RewriteRule (^/image/.*) http://otherdomain.com$1 [P]
```

and maybe this will work to

```
2 ProxyPass /image http://otherdomain.com/image
```